# When do Heroku dynos use swap memory?

Tags: performance, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn

I'm hosting my Rails 4.1.4 project with 2 Unicorn processes on free dyno for my development server. After the app running for a while, sometimes I feel getting slow. I added New relic, logentries, and enable log-runtime-metrics. Then I look at New relic and logentries

[image]

```
» heroku web.1  - - source=web.1 dyno=heroku.21274089.82eb32b4-c547-4041-b452-d3fedae05ee9 sample#load_avg_1m=0.00 sample#load_avg_5m=0.00 sample#load_avg_15m=0.01
» heroku web.1  - - source=web.1 dyno=heroku.21274089.82eb32b4-c547-4041-b452-d3fedae05ee9 sample#memory_total=393.41MB sample#memory_rss=368.38MB sample#memory_cache=4.47MB sample#memory_swap=20.56MB sample#memory_pgpgin=121244pages sample#memory_pgpgout=25796pages
```

What I don't understand is my dyno’s memory is only `sample#memory_rss=368.38MB`, but why it already uses swap memory `sample#memory_swap=20.56MB`? Because from what I thought from heroku article https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#memory-behavior, it should switch to swap memory if it reaches dyno's memory which is 512 Mb for free dyno.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was seeing significant swap even when using only 50% of available RAM in my app, so I asked. Here's a quote from their support team:

> We leave Ubuntu's swappiness at its default of 60 on our runtimes, including PX dynos.

A value of 60 ensures that your app will begin swapping well before it reaches max memory. The Linux kernel parameter `vm.swappiness` ranges from 0 to 100, with 0 indicating no swap and 100 indicating always swap.

So when running on Heroku you should expect your application to swap even if the footprint of your app is far smaller than the advertised RAM of your dyno.

Comment: So how to you decide to fix it? Because using swap space will degrade application performance.

Comment: @Samnang there is no fix that users can make. This needs to be fixed by Heroku.

Comment: According to Heroku this shouldn't affect application performance. "30-50MB of swap, as long as your app still has free memory shouldn't impact your performance. This memory being put to swap by linux is non-used one. It's moved there by the system because it hasn't been used for quite some time, and allows releasing some memory in your ram."

Comment: @Lev that reply is a bit dismissive. This is a potential performance issue for anyone who approaches max memory, even occasionally. The reply you quote could be rephrased as "performance is good as long as you don't approach the RAM limit". A swap setting of 60 assumes that apps are better-off swapping, which is rarely the case for performance-minded systems.

Comment: @BrianPO'Rourke so any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: "Buy larger dynos or use fewer web processes within dynos" would probably work if you don't mind paying more. Also, be mindful of memory use by gems and see if you can replace some heavy ones like devise with simpler solutions.